# rtweet work without token ? event with token this is not taking tweet from my twiter dev account

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

Hello every body I will try to be as clear a possible beacause I have a few question

I'm new to the package rtweet,
I notice tha when i use search_tweet and stream tweet my devloppeur acount on twiter doesn't not increase my number of pull up tweet.
so I try to empty my environnement and retry and it woorks

```
> (file_name=gsub(" ", "_",gsub(":", "_",paste0("file_test_",Sys.Date(),".json"),fixed = TRUE)))
tweet2=stream_tweets("covid vaccin",timeout = 30,file_name = file_name)
tweet=search_tweets("tweeter",n =10 )
```

So my question is why since we need a dev acount to acces this app normaly, is there a limite ? is this a bug ? this nowlege will drasticly change my program.

Comment: There is indeed a quota per API token.
You can query how many calls per endpoint and the time that the quota will reset in a table through `rate_limit(token = your_token_object_here).

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez, Yes i know for the rate limite , but what i don't understand is, when you clear your environnement and try the function without any token (like in the exemple) it's working. i would like to know why and if we can use that fact.
also when i put my token my number of "pull of tweet" don't increase wherease i have tweet result. seems paradoxal to me. thank you very much for your help